# Bought Japanese Phone. Keyboard is weird (small spacebar, etc). How to fix?

Tags: keyboard, samsung-galaxy-s-9

Title. I attached a screenshot of the keyboard.
I would download a third party keyboard, but I don't like how they look.
There also seems to be no options to change the layout at all in settings.[image: keyboard]

Comment: Just install Google Keyboard. Flagging for closure as requesting app recommendation.

Comment: Acejavelin, that's not a solution to the problem. That's merely avoiding it. I need to find a fix for it.

Comment: A solution to what, changing the layout? That's just the normal Samsung keyboard and the layout it uses, it's not a "weird Japanese" thing. If you don't like it, change it to a different keyboard.

Comment: I'd recommend you [AnySoftKeyboard](https://f-droid.org/en/packages/com.menny.android.anysoftkeyboard/) - High flexibility, customizable, free and open-source. Unless your keyboard settings allow for it, there's no other way to change the layout.

Answer (score 0):

If there is no setting to remove the bottom arrow keys, there is no way. You can try to set Japanese as the only language, hoping that the globe on the left will disappear so your space has a little more "space".